# How get value of static field in another package's class via reflection

Tags: java, reflection

How I can get value of static field in another package?

I need know `string` values of `.R` class or similar.
I try use something like this:

```
Class.forName("com.notmypackage.R$string").getDeclaredFields();
```

or in detailed case:

```
for (Field field : Class.forName("com.android.webview.R$string").getDeclaredFields()) {
}
```

but none success, got exception:

```
11-08 10:02:38.038 4983-4983/com.mypack W/System.err: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.webview.R$string
11-08 10:02:38.038 4983-4983/com.mypack W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
11-08 10:02:38.038 4983-4983/com.mypack W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:309)
11-08 10:02:38.038 4983-4983/com.mypack W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:273)
```

There any way to get alien `***.R$string` values?

Comment: "got exception" could you be a bit more specific? why do you need to use reflection anyway?

Comment: @Stultuske, I added more details

Answer (score 1):

You can get static fields of class by:

```
Field[] fields= Class.forName("com.android.webview.R").getDeclaredFields();
List<Field> staticFields = new ArrayList<Field>();
for (Field field : fields) {
    if (java.lang.reflect.Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers())) {
        // if you want to get String fields, check this
        // field.getType().equals(String.class)
        staticFields.add(field);
    }
}
```

Or specify field name:

```
Field field= Class.forName("com.android.webview.R").getDeclaredField("field");
```

Then get value:

```
System.out.println(field.get(null));
```

It throws `IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, SecurityException, ClassNotFoundException`

Comment: Unfortunatelly not work for me now: 'W/System.err: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.webview.R
W/System.err: at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)'